# How to use kwargs in matplotlib.axes.Axes.arrow python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I'm working from arrow_simple_demo.py [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/arrow_simple_demo.html) which I have already modified to be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes()
ax.arrow(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1)
```

however, I want to change the line style of the arrow to dashed using a kwarg. The arrow docs suggest it is possible. [arrow docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.arrow.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.arrow)

So I tried to give arrow the **kwargs argument to import:

```
kwargs = {linestyle:'--'}
```

Now my code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes()
kwargs={linestyle:'--'}
ax.arrow(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1, **kwargs)
```

But the result is:

```
NameError: name 'linestyle' is not defined
```

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me if I am using the kwargs correctly, and whether I need to import Patch from matplotlib's patches class to make this work. The statement "Other valid kwargs (inherited from :class:`Patch`)" which is in the arrow docs above the listing of kwargs makes me think it might be necessary. I have also been looking at the patches docs to figure that question out. [here](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/api/patches_api.html)

EDIT:

Code finished when I passed linestyle key as a string, but I am not getting the dashed arrow line that I was hoping for.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.axes()
kwargs={'linestyle':'--'}
ax.arrow(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1, **kwargs)
```

see picture:

[arrow plot solid line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9EZE.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key of your `kwargs` dictionary should be a string. In you code, python looks for an object called `linestyle` which does not exist.

```
kwargs = {'linestyle':'--'}
```

unfortunately, doing is not enough to produce the desired effect. The line *is* dashed, but the problem is that the arrow is drawn with a closed path and the dashes are overlaid on top of one another, which cancels the effect. You can see the dashed line by plotting a thicker arrow.

```
ax = plt.axes()
kwargs={'linestyle':'--', 'lw':2, 'width':0.05}
ax.arrow(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1, **kwargs)
```

[image]

If you want a simple dashed arrow, you have to use a simpler arrow, using `annotate`

```
ax = plt.axes()
kwargs={'linestyle':'--', 'lw':2}
ax.annotate("", xy=(0.5, 0.5), xytext=(0, 0),
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", **kwargs))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh such a simple mistake! The code finishes now but still a solid line for some reason?

Comment: See my edit to the question that reflects your advice. Can you confirm that the arrow line is still solid on your system? It still shows solid on mine.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I will have to use annotate after all.